# Применение Angular и Node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular2, angular4

Появилась задача подобрать framework'и для проекта, на который будет приходить много запросов от пользователей на запись в базу данных сообщений(и вывод получателю) и др. информации, а также загрузки множества файлов на сервере. Для front-end'a есть мысли использовать AngularJS или Angular. Т.к. этот framework еще предстоит изучать, слышал, что angularjs примитивнее остальных версий. Хотелось бы совет от профи:

1. Какая версия angular'a предпочтительнее для front-end'a?
2. Годен ли для подобного проекта back-end Node.JS ?
3. Т.к. проектирование предстоит на винде, есть ли костыли при
   дальнейшем переносе node.js на сервер под debian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Актуальную версию всегда можно посмотреть на [официальном сайте Angular](https://angular.io/). Советую использовать именно Angular, а не AngularJS, т.к. второй морально устарел. На данный момент актуальная версия - stable v5.1.1. 
2) Backend на ноде - очень хорошее решение для приложения с множеством подключений. С файлами тоже самое. Не прогадаешь. Единственное - придется свыкаться с приколами ноды и вообще серверного js. 
3) Пиши сразу на Linux, т.к. это все равно потом будет крутиться на сервере под линукс. Плюс линукс поддерживается в этом плане намного лучше винды. Костыли могут быть с путями, а так же с настройками самого сервера.

Comment: С Linux тогда либо виртуалку сделаю и буду под ней, либо второй системой поставлю. Кстати, тут принципиально важна версия Linux, или по факту не важно?

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов ну если совсем не знаком с линуксом, тогда ставь Mint или Ubuntu, если есть базовые знания - Debian. Разница дистрибутивов имеется в интерфейсе, пакетных менеджерах, структуре ОС (это далеко не все).

Comment: В приоритете производительность, меньшая загрузка. На debian.в своё время немного работал. Хотелось бы, наиболее подходящую ось, для выше описанных задач. Чтобы была возможность установки на домашний комп, и дальнейший перенос на VDS.

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов бери debian и не ошибешься.